# What is the correct way to use Validators.required True?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm not able to properly validate the checkbox, what I'm trying to do is the following:

The checkbox should be selected as the default, so the value will be `true` (boolean), if the user deselects the value it will be `false` (boolean).

With these results I activate the checklist and also make other business rules with the validated form.

What am I doing wrong?

**FORM COMPONENT**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contract-form',
  template: `
    <app-form [class]="'flex__display align__items__center bg__color__red__light'" [fmGroup]="contractForm">
      <app-input
        (onclick)="sendValue()"
        [class]="'cursor__pointer height__rem__2 width__rem__2 margin__xy__2'"
        [fmControl]="contractForm.controls.checkbox"
        [type]="'checkbox'"
        [checked]="checkboxValue"
      >
      </app-input>
{{contractForm.controls.checkbox.valid| json}}
{{contractForm.controls.checkbox.errors| json}}
      <app-span>
        Declaro que conheço e concordo com as
        <app-span [class]="'cursor__pointer text__color__blue__dark text__decoration__underline'">
          Cláusulas Gerais do Contrato.
        </app-span>
      </app-span>
    </app-form>
  `,
})
export class ContractFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() clauseClick = new EventEmitter<IContractFormValue>();
  @Input() protected set setDisabledForm(isDisabled: boolean) {
    isDisabled ? this.contractForm.controls.checkbox.disable() : this.contractForm.controls.checkbox.enable();
  }
  contractForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(protected readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.contractForm = formBuilder.group({
      checkbox: formBuilder.control(true, Validators.requiredTrue)
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  get checkboxValue(): boolean {
    return Boolean(this.contractForm.controls.checkbox.value);
  }

  sendValue(): void {
    this.contractForm.controls.checkbox.patchValue(!this.checkboxValue);
    this.clauseClick.emit({ isAccepted: this.checkboxValue });
  }
}
```

**LOGIN FORM**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `
    <input
      (click)="onclick.emit($event)"
      [formControl]="fmControl"
      [class]="class"
      [type]="type"
      [placeholder]="placeholder"
      [autocomplete]="autocomplete"
      [minLength]="minlength"
      [maxLength]="maxlength"
      [readonly]="readonly"
      [autofocus]="autofocus"
      [checked]="checked"
      [required]="required"
    >
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      input {
        width: 100%;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class InputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onclick = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  @Input() fmControl!: FormControl;
  @Input() class = '';
  @Input() type = 'text';
  @Input() placeholder = '';
  @Input() autocomplete = 'on';
  @Input() minlength = 1;
  @Input() maxlength = 524288;
  @Input() readonly = false;
  @Input() autofocus = false;
  @Input() checked = false;
  @Input() required = true;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: your code looks right, I tried to recreate a small example and it works https://stackblitz.com/edit/required-validator-checkbox what are you seeing, any errors ? maybe detection change doesnt pick it up cause it's in separate component ?

Comment: When you click the value it is "true" (string), and then if you click it again it stops issuing the value.